How scopes are added to token in Azure Entra ID?
I am working on a project were I am trying to generate token using Authorization Code flow in Azure Entra ID. I have created custom scopes and trying to include those scopes in token. While intiating the authorization I am including required scopes using the scopes query parameter. Every time I add new scopes consent screen is prompted. I am giving user consent to the requested scopes. I have observed that Azure Entra ID includes the already consented scopes by the user inside the token even If I haven't requested for them while initiating Authorization.
For e.g.,

Token Generatation for First Time
I have included 3 scopes namely Patient, Practitioner and Observation.
After successful authentication and authorization a token is generated with 3 scopes inside the scp claim.

Token Generation for Second Time
I have included 3 scopes namely Patient, Observation and Condition
After successful authenticaitno and authorization a token is generated with 4 scopes inside the scp claim.


Despite of requesting 3 scopes I have received 4 scopes. The extra scope is Practitioner scope which I consented while generating Token for First Time.
I google about this behaviour of Azure Entra ID for managing scopes but couldn't see any relevant information for the same.
Can anyone clarify on the above behaviour as well as my observation about adding the consented scopes inside the token even if not requested. If my observation is right can you point out to links or documents which can justify the same. Any assistance would be of great help to me.

Azure Entra ID includes all the scopes previously granted to an application in the access token, not just the scopes in the current request. This is why you are seeing the previously consented scopes in the token even if they were not requested in the current request. This behavior is by design and is intended to reduce the number of consent prompts for users.
When a user or an administrator consents to a set of permissions for an application, those permissions are granted to the application in that user's context. If the application later requests a subset of those permissions, the token issued will still include all the permissions that have been granted to the application for that user. This means if you've given consent to three scopes initially and then only request two scopes in a subsequent token request, the token may still contain all three scopes, because the consent for the third scope is still valid.
This behavior is linked to the concept of static (.default) and dynamic consent in the Microsoft identity platform. When .default is used in a scope request, it is essentially asking for "all the static permissions that have been granted to this application." If explicit consent has already been granted for a set of scopes, a token request with .default will result in a token containing all of those scopes.
To avoid requesting unnecessary scopes, it is recommended to request only the scopes that are required for the current operation. You can incrementally request more scopes as the application performs operations that require those scopes.
References:

Authorize applications, resources, and workloads with Microsoft Entra ID
Developer guidance for Microsoft Entra Conditional Access
Understanding delegated access

